# jQuery custom html5 error messages

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using HTML5 to validate a form and change the error message text using
setCustomValidity. Except for some reason I just can't get this to work. I'm getting no error messages in the console or anything. I'm trying to take what is in the "data-error" attribute and use that as the custom error message but can't figure this out I've spent hours on this.

JQUERY

```
$aboutUs.find("#headerForm :input").each(function(){ 
  var $this = $(this); 
  var errorMessage = $this.attr("data-error");
   for (var i = 0; i < $this.length; i++) {
     $this[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
     e.target.setCustomValidity("test");
     if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
     e.target.setCustomValidity(e.target.getAttribute(errorMessage));
     }
     };
    }                        
   });
```

HTML FORM

```
<input id="firstName" type="text" required data-error="First Name Message" />
<input id="lastName" type="text" required data-error="Last Name Message" />
<input id="phone" type="text" required data-error="Phone Message" />
```

Comment: People here often like to isolate a problem from the rest of the website. This helps mental focus.  Can you make a jsfiddle that contains the problematic behavior and paste the jsfiddle link  into your question by clicking "edit"? If you do, someone will probably help.   http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Taken in isolation, $aboutUs looks odd. Is it set somewhere else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your statement `var errorMessage = $this.attr("data-error");` already gets the message, and then you are trying to get the attribute with the name as that of the message. `e.target.setCustomValidity(e.target.getAttribute(errorMessage));`. `errorMessage` in this statement is the message not the attribute name instead it is the **message** itself. So you probably meant `e.target.setCustomValidity(errorMessage);`

By the way you could just use `$this.data("error")` to retrieve the `data-*` value, provided it doesn't change on the fly.

So try this:-

```
$aboutUs.find("#headerForm :input").each(function(){ 
  var $this = $(this); 
  var errorMessage = $this.data("error");
   for (var i = 0; i < $this.length; i++) {
     $this[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
     if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
          e.target.setCustomValidity(errorMessage);
     }
     };
    }                        
   });
```

Since you are using jquery just simplify this:

```
$aboutUs.find("#headerForm :input").on('invalid', function (e) {
    var errorMessage = $(this).data("error");
   e.target.setCustomValidity("");
    if (e.target.validity.valueMissing) {
         e.target.setCustomValidity(errorMessage);

    }

});
```

Comment: thanks for replying but I'm lost this isn't working for me. If I try to throw a console.log inside of this **$this[i].oninvalid = function(e) {** I'm not getting anything.

Comment: When is the `$this[i].oninvalid`  handler invoked?

Comment: I'm not even sure if it is. I'm pretty new to jquery how would I check and thus invoke it?

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a fiddle.

Comment: @DelmonYoung Ok. Now see this should resolve your issue. Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rFzUT/ Provided and also make sure your elements are selected. can't see your html so cannot predict if your selectors are correct.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response @PSL but what you have on jsfiddle worked perfect! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: In the jsfiddle, when the error message appears and then you fill it out and submit again, it doesn't validate the next field, it just focus on the valid input field. When you click submit again, then it validates the next required field. So you have to click twice to trigger the subsequent validation. 

Tested in both Chrome and Firefox. In Firefox, a blank error message popup appears after filling out and submitting. So it appears after filling out a required field that previously failed validation, the oninvalid event for that field is still triggered.